# How do we decode the image formed by a gravitational lens?

Tags: gravity, astronomy, gravitational-lensing

Using our own sun as a gravitational lens, we can [scrutinize planetary surfaces in distant solar systems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642274366) with a good deal of accuracy. How do we translate this smeared out and curved image into a normal photo style image?

Related: [The Sun as a gravitational lens](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25498/the-sun-as-a-gravitational-lens?rq=1)

Comment: The short answer is that it is not an easy task.  [Here's an arxiv paper about one technique.](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0311508)

Comment: I would think that it's a relatively easier task when we know the precise geometry of the lens - our Sun. The paper you linked seemed to deal with the general case of a galaxy-scale lens of irregular shape.